# Yii2 relations activerecords

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, relationship

For landingPage model make method

```
public function getLpBlocks()
```

receive  LpBlock's for LandingPage
1. from relations with lpWidgets
2. block for LandingPage it is block's LpType
what is difference these two methods

tables here

```
CREATE TABLE `lpType` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`rule` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`route` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`view` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`lpName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`lpBody` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`lpMetaTitle` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`lpMetaKeywords` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`lpMetaDescription` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `UK_slug` (`slug`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8     COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `lpWidget` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`landingPageId` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`blockId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`widgetId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`sort` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`options` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `K_lpId_blockId_sort` (`landingPageId`,`blockId`,`sort`),
KEY `K_blockId` (`blockId`),
KEY `K_widgetId` (`widgetId`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_lpBlock_id` FOREIGN KEY (`blockId`) REFERENCES `lpBlock`         (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `FK_lpWidget_landingPageId` FOREIGN KEY (`landingPageId`)     REFERENCES `landingPage` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `FK_widget_id` FOREIGN KEY (`widgetId`) REFERENCES `widget`     (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=292 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `lpBlock` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`typeId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `UK_slug_typeId` (`slug`,`typeId`),
KEY `K_typeId` (`typeId`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_lpType_id` FOREIGN KEY (`typeId`) REFERENCES `lpType` (`id`)     ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=157 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8     COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `landingPage` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`lpTypeId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`body` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`metaTitle` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`metaKeywords` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`metaDescription` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`semanticKernel` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `UK_url` (`url`),
KEY `K_lpTypeId` (`lpTypeId`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_landingPage_lpTypeId` FOREIGN KEY (`lpTypeId`) REFERENCES     `lpType` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

or please give me links for documentation

Comment: you can take a look a the guide  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html

Comment: sorry but i can't understand how do this, can you linck some samples

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-active-record--cms-27434

Comment: Other guide is :  http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/

Comment: If you use `gii` to generate your models, it will also generate all the required relationships for you. Then you can learn how it works

Comment: I try but gii doen't make this method

Comment: Because you don't have foreign keys. Add them, and then generate models by `Gii`.